# Pipeline occurs "Could not resolve host" when I use Gogs and Drone to build a CI/CD platform

Tags: git, docker, centos, drone.io, gogs

### Physical machine `hosts` file

```
192.168.32.103 gogs.com
192.168.32.105 drone.com
```

### Gogs virtual machine `/etc/hosts` file

```
192.168.32.105 drone.com
```

### Drone virtual machine `/etc/hosts` file

```
192.168.32.103 gogs.com
```

The following commands are all operated on the VMware virtual machine.

### Gogs Docker Run Command

```shell
docker run -d \
  -p 8022:22 -p 80:3000 \
  --add-host=drone.com:192.168.32.105 \
  --name=gogs -v /srv/gogs-data:/data gogs/gogs:latest
```

### Drone Server Run Command

```
docker run \
  --volume=/var/lib/drone:/data \
  --add-host=gogs.com:192.168.32.103 \
  --env=DRONE_AGENTS_ENABLED=true \
  --env=DRONE_GOGS_SERVER=http://gogs.com \
  --env=DRONE_RPC_SECRET=Hascalator \
  --env=DRONE_SERVER_HOST=drone.com \
  --env=DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=http \
  --publish=80:80 \
  --publish=443:443 \
  --restart=always \
  --detach=true \
  --name=drone-server \
  drone/drone:1
```

### Drone Runner Docker Run Command

```
docker run -d \
  --add-host=gogs.com:192.168.32.103 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -e DRONE_RPC_PROTO=http \
  -e DRONE_RPC_HOST=drone-server \
  -e DRONE_RPC_SECRET=Hascalator \
  -e DRONE_RUNNER_CAPACITY=2 \
  -e DRONE_RUNNER_NAME=${HOSTNAME} \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  --restart always \
  --name drone-runner-docker \
  --link drone-server:drone-server \
  drone/drone-runner-docker:1
```

### `.drone.yml` file content

```
kind: pipeline
name: Test Drone
type: docker
steps:
  - name: Print Hello World
    image: centos
    commands:
      - echo 'Hello, Drone'
  - name: Print Secrets
    image: centos
    environment:
      AppID: 
        from_secret: APP_ID
      AppSecret: 
        from_secret: APP_SECRET
    commands:
      - echo $$AppID
      - echo $$AppSecret
```

### When I push origin master, the Pipeline occurs "Could not resolve host"

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /drone/src/.git/
+ git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:
fatal: unable to access 'http://gogs.com/yokefellow/drone-practice.git/': Could not resolve host: gogs.com
```

### It's pingable in these two containers(drone-server,drone-runner-docker)

```
[root@drone ~]# docker container exec -it  drone-server /bin/sh
/ # ping gogs.com
PING gogs.com (192.168.32.103): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.629 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.637 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.847 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.451 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.804 ms
^C
--- gogs.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.451/0.673/0.847 ms
```

```
[root@drone ~]# docker container exec -it  drone-runner-docker /bin/sh
/ # ping gogs.com
PING gogs.com (192.168.32.103): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.759 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.850 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.648 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.753 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.32.103: seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.753 ms
^C
--- gogs.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.648/0.752/0.850 ms
```

Comment: Yokefellow. Recently, I also meet this problem. I have see drone docker plugin document have a parameter `add_host`. [https://docs.drone.io/plugins/popular/docker/]. I have try this parameter but it not work, maybe my `.drone.yml` file is wrong. Are you use `plugins/docker` image to push your image? Maybe this is a director to resolve this.